# Rails - extend attributes method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a group of input, for which I expect a large amount data (list of objects), so I want this input on create/update action to be wrapped inside of ActiveRecord transaction.

There is model `Student`, which has_one `Account`.

```
ACCOUNT_FIELDS=[:name, :surname, :email, :phone, :activated]
  has_one :account, :as => :account_holder, autosave: true, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_associated_extended :account

  ACCOUNT_FIELDS.each do |action|
    define_method action do
      get_or_build_account.send(action)
    end
    setter_action = action.to_s + "="
    define_method setter_action do |arg|
     get_or_build_account.send(setter_action, arg)
    end
  end
```

here I made a reader/writer methods, so `@student.name` will return related data from account, also I can assign it through `@student` thanks to `autosave`.

**Issue**: as I said, I want it to be wrapped inside of transaction, so in my controller I don't save anything. Each student is assigned like this

```
student.attributes = #...data
```

Where student later on passed to transaction block.

But! For this specific model I want to `student.attributes` also return fields from `ACCOUNT_FIELDS`.

Normally it works with `student.account_attributes` but as I said, later `student` is processed in transaction, and it is made with module, which I want to be reusable for some other models (which doesn't need this logic).

**So rather than modifying my module code with some conditions, I want instance of this model to return needed account fields when just called** `self.attributes`

```
@student.attributes #=> :school_id => 1, :name => "John"...
```

where name is `self.name` from `self.account.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def attributes
  new_attributes={}
  ACCOUNT_FIELDS.each do |field|
    new_attributes[field]=self.send(field)
  end
  super.merge(new_attributes)
end
```